# How should I "create commands with implicit contexts" in GHC's ghci

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, type-safety, ghci

I'm aware that `ghci` effectively works inside the `IO` monad.   Initially I'd imagined that `ghci` might handle another monad or a transformation of `IO`, but the documentation make it clear this doesn't work.

Instead I tried using implicit parameters, but `ghci` barfed on all attempts to communicate the implicit parameter from ghci, except for locally binding the implicit parameter in a `let .. in`, which is totally worthless.

```
foo <- meow_for_t "chicken"
bar <- let ?foo = foo in purr "tuna"
```

where our included module says :

```
purr (Eq t, ?foo :: Foo t) => String -> IO ()
purr s = ...
```

I would've expected that `purr "tuna"` alone should've worked fine with either `foo <-` or `?foo <-` or at least `let ?foo = foo` sans `in`, but nothing worked.

I could perhaps create global `IORef`s using stunts like :

```
foo :: IORef (Foo Sometype)
foo = unsafePerformIO $ newIORef []
```

but obviously I'd sacrifice my lovely polymorphism in `Foo`.

What is the "correct way" to create top level command `purr` in `ghci` that modifies a `ghci` global state in a type safe way?

Ideally, there should be another family of commands that recreates said global state with a new type, after which point `purr` should continue acting in a type safe way, just with a new type.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit parameters are a GHC extension. You can turn it on with `:set -XImplicitParams` on ghci.